# Searching next item in list if object isn't in the list

Tags: python, list, csv, search

I'm attempting to learn how to search csv files. In this example, I've worked out how to search a specific column (date of birth) and how to search indexes within that column to get the year of birth.

I can search for greater than a specific year - e.g. typing in 45 will give me everyone born in or after 1945, but the bit I'm stuck on is if I type in a year not specifically in the csv/list I will get an error saying the year isn't in the list (which it isn't).

What I'd like to do is iterate through the years in the column until the next year that is in the list is found and print anything greater than that.

I've tried a few bits with iteration, but my brain has finally ground to a halt. Here is my code so far...

```
data=[]
with open("users.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
print(data)

lookup = input("Please enter a year of birth to start at (eg 67): ")

#lookupint = int(lookup)


#searching column 3 eg [3]
#but also searching index 6-8 in column 3
#eg [6:8] being the year of birth within the DOB field
col3 = [x[3][6:8] for x in data]

#just to check if col3 is showing the right data
print(col3)
print ("test3")



#looks in column 3 for 'lookup' which is a string
#in the table
if lookup in col3: #can get rid of this
    output = col3.index(lookup)
    print (col3.index(lookup))
    print("test2")

    for k in range (0, len(col3)):
        #looks for data that is equal or greater than YOB
        if col3[k] >= lookup:
           print(data[k])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should ask yourself: Do I want to search csv files, or do I want to search a list of strings/other Python data-structures. I think it is easier to go for the last one and read in the csv file and put it into the appropriate data structure.

Comment: What about: `for years in col3: if years == lookup: do something elif years > lookup: do something else`

Comment: Thanks Elmex80 - it's a list I want to search as the csv puts the data into a list - apologies as I didn't exactly make this clear. Terence, thanks for the suggestion - I tried something similar to this but because years wasn't in the list, it threw up an error.